# Docker Abusing Swap on macOS Monterey

Tags: virtual-memory, docker

On macOS Monterey, the Docker process is using many GB of swap (virtual memory). So much swap, in fact, that my SSD filled up and caused file corruption.
**Here are some things I've done to try to limit the swap usage**:

Running the container with `--memory-swap` limited:

```bsh
docker run -dp <port stuff> -v <bind volume stuff> --cpus="2" -m 2g --memory-swap 6g --name <name> <image>
```

Limiting swap usage in Docker Desktop:
[image: Swap limited to 512 MB]

**Here's what continues to happen**:
After 24 hours (the swap usage increases throughout the day):
[image: Activity Monitor: Docker using 14.49 GB of VM and 14.51 GB total Memory; com.apple.Virtualization.VirtualMachine using 1.58 GB of VM and 2.00 GB of total Memory]

---

[image: Disk Utility: VM Partition using 19.33 GB]
The Docker process is the one using tons of swap, while the container (`com.apple.Virtualizations.VirtualMachine`) stays within its limits.

Restarting the container does not free up swap, while restarting the docker daemon does.

*Is there anything I can do to prevent this abuse of swap? I don't want to disable swap entirely, but I'd like to keep Docker down to a few GB at most.*

Comment: You appear to be using the experimental settings for Docker for Mac - Please disable those first to see if it corrects the issue.

Comment: I'll try that and wait 24 hours.

Comment: You are using a beta OS and experimental features of Docker. Expect issues, especially like this. Report the issue to Docker

Answer (score 1):

Disabling **Use the new Virtualization framework** in **Experimental Features** seems to have solved the issue. I will submit a bug report to Docker.